# Nuget version restrictions

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, semantic-versioning

I'm using Nuget `4.3.0.4406` to pack an assembly with version `5.2.29.181212.8244-RC` but I get

> 2018-12-12T08:44:02.8053309Z ##[error]The nuget command failed with
>   exit code(1) and error('5.2.29.181212.8244-RC' is not a valid version
>   string. Parameter name: value)

The versioning is NOT semver compliant but Nuget puts on restrictions and it's not clear which..? Does this mean Nuget not just supports SemVer but enforces it? I found [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2735) but I'm not sure what they mean with the `SpecialVersion`?

Basically I just want `x.y.z.[date+buildid](-rc)` where `x.y.z` are tied to a specification version so it can not be ommitted (we don't own that versioning).

## Update

- `9.9.9.1812129999-rc` works but `9.9.9.18121299999-rc` and `9.9.9.9812129999-rc` don't, where is this specified? (it's a numeric size limitation not a string length)

Comment: NuGet's [NuGetVersion code is here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/NuGetVersion.cs). You can see the constructors take `int`s, hence any value you put in the numeric part of the version needs to fit in an `int`. If the error message isn't clear, you could (report an issue)[https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues] so they can improve the error message in this scenario.

Comment: thanks, I was actually searching for that earlier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [NuGet Package Versioning Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning) on Microsoft Docs:

> With NuGet 4.3.0+ and Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3+, NuGet supports Semantic Versioning 2.0.0.
>
> Certain semantics of SemVer v2.0.0 are not supported in older clients. NuGet considers a package version to be SemVer v2.0.0 specific if either of the following statements is true:
>
> - The pre-release label is dot-separated, for example, 1.0.0-alpha.1
> - The version has build-metadata, for example, 1.0.0+githash
>
> For nuget.org, a package is defined as a SemVer v2.0.0 package if either of the following statements is true:
>
> - The package's own version is SemVer v2.0.0 compliant but not SemVer v1.0.0 compliant, as defined above.
> - Any of the package's dependency version ranges has a minimum or maximum version that is SemVer v2.0.0 compliant but not SemVer v1.0.0 compliant, defined above; for example, [1.0.0-alpha.1, ).

Of course you can find the Semmantic Versioning Specification at [semver.org](https://semver.org/). I think you're especially interested in [spec-item10](https://semver.org/#spec-item-10):

> Build metadata MAY be denoted by appending a plus sign and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch or pre-release version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty. Build metadata SHOULD be ignored when determining version precedence. Thus two versions that differ only in the build metadata, have the same precedence. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha+001, 1.0.0+20130313144700, 1.0.0-beta+exp.sha.5114f85.

Your version would become something like `x.y.z(-rc)+[date+buildid]`

Comment: Hey @rickvdbosch, that's not what we want, the version should have both x.y.z (the spec version) and the date+buildid (that's what WE own). It's not relevant to the pre-release part.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer: spec-item10 gives you room to add metadata like in the example at the end of my answer: `x.y.z(-rc)+[date+buildid]`

Comment: I'm aware of the metadata but `Build metadata SHOULD be ignored when determining version precedence. Thus two versions that differ only in the build metadata, have the same precedence.`

Comment: you could put the date as the prerelease label, which I would argue fits better with SemVer's design/goals.

Comment: or if you don't use the 3rd segment, split the date from the time and use `x.y.date.time+metadata`, although that strictly isn't semver and relies on a quirk of NuGet's implementation since they need to also support `System.Version` style `a.b.c.d` versions.